# What's wrong with my Timer thread?

Tags: android, timer

I'm updating a picture by using timer, but it causes fatal performance problem. Then I print logs and find out my timer runs faster rather than 1500.
So what's the problem?

schedule at wrong rate:

> startToDraw().353: System.currentTimeMillis() = 1332742387400
>   startToDraw().353: System.currentTimeMillis() = 1332742387410
>   startToDraw().353: System.currentTimeMillis() = 1332742387438
>   startToDraw().353: System.currentTimeMillis() = 1332742387449
>   startToDraw().353: System.currentTimeMillis() = 1332742387472

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!isDestroyed) {
            try {
                Log.i(getClass().getName(), "startToDraw().353: System.currentTimeMillis() = " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                handler.sendMessage(new Message());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}, 0, 1500);
```

Comment: I don't see where you wait? `sendMessage` returns immediately.

Comment: have you tried adding sleep to the main thread?

Comment: Try to use Thread.sleep(milliseconds);

Comment: @thecoOw : problem is  at this line `while (!isDestroyed)`

Comment: On android using TimerTask is not recommended. Check this link http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html for an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are entering a while loop that runs repeatedly.  You probably just want to make a check if you are in an invalid state and then if you are, don't perform the task.  So I would change:

```
while (!isDestroyed) {
    try {
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "startToDraw().353: System.currentTimeMillis() = " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        handler.sendMessage(new Message());
    } catch (Exception e) {
}
```

to:

```
if (!isDestroyed) {
    try {
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "startToDraw().353: System.currentTimeMillis() = " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        handler.sendMessage(new Message());
    } catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply!I should use if(...) rather than while(...)!